# Dockerfile with envsubt

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html 
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 
#COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d 
COPY nginx/nginx.template /etc/nginx/conf.d 
EXPOSE 80 
CMD envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

My nginx.conf file.

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;


  }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

 }
}
```

My template file

```
server {

  listen ${PORT};

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    index  index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

  }
}
```

Above is my dockerfile. After starting container, I've checked config.d folder and didn't find any nginx.conf file. Seem like it didn't generate any file by using envsubt. But then I jumped to interactive mode and run envsubt command it did generate the file. What seem to be the problem in my case?

Comment: My initial expectation is that `envsubst`, being a GNU tool, wouldn't be installed in an Alpine (Busybox) based image, but then your container wouldn't start.  What are the actual commands you're running to look for the file?

Comment: They've already installed gettext (envsubst) in nginx:alpine. Lately, I found out that the problem might not be the envsubst but using redirect command ( > ) was not generating any file. I have test a simple command like CMD echo "foo" > /etc/bar.txt and I get no bar.txt file at all.